# Spring Custom annotazioni - Validation message not showing parameter

Tags: spring, validation

I have a custom annotation in my Spring Boot application, and it works, despite of the validation message...

This is my custom annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ReservationValidatorJSON.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidReservationJSON {

    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int day();

}
```

and its validator

```
public class ReservationValidatorJSON implements ConstraintValidator<ValidReservationJSON, String> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReservationValidatorJSON.class);

    private int day;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidReservationJSON date) {
        day = date.day();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String date, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime dateToValidate = null;
        try {
            dateToValidate = new DateTime(sdf.parse(date));
            DateTime now = new DateTime();

            if (dateToValidate != null) {
                return dateToValidate.isBefore(now.plusDays(day));
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

I use this annotation in this way

```
@ValidReservationJSON(day=31)
private String fromDate;
```

Then i have, in my message properties, this field

```
ValidReservationJSON.fromDate = The beginning date cannot be after {day} days from now
```

When validation fails, i would expect a message like

```
The beginning date cannot be after 31 days from now
```

But i keep getting

```
The beginning date cannot be after {day} days from now
```

Answer (score 0):

try this message instead 
`ValidReservationJSON.fromDate =  The beginning date cannot be after {1} days from now`